# In Star Trek V, why was the Klingon Bird-Of-Prey hanging close to Earth?

Tags: star-trek, klingon, the-final-frontier

The sequence at the [beginning of Star Trek V](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LbQ7SMSpSto): The Final Frontier shows the Pioneer 10 probe being destroyed by a Klingon Bird-Of-Prey.

Given the speed of the probe, even in 2287, the year the movie takes place in-universe, it wouldn't be very far from Earth's solar system. Which means that the cloaked Bird-Of-Prey was, for some reason, discreetly flying close to the capital of the Federation while the Organian Peace Treaty was in force.

Was it ever explained why that Bird-Of-Prey was so close to Earth?

Comment: The Organian treaty didn't forbid fighting, nor did it mean that the Klingons couldn't enter Federation space; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/194437/20774

Comment: True, but that doesn't answer the question: why was this Klingon ship so close to Earth?

Comment: The Klingons were afraid of another Star Trek I. Who can blame them?

Comment: Surely there's no way V'GER a.k.a. fictional Voyager probe could have made it far enough into space to reach a planet full of super-advanced robots, could it? The original one made like 140AU in 40+ years -- assume 10 times the speed and 300 years, and it's still zero distance (something like 0.1ly) in astronomical terms. Except, well, wormholes, and magic.

Comment: DECKER: Voyager VI ...disappeared into what they used to call a black hole.
KIRK: It must have emerged sometime on the far side of the Galaxy and fell into the machine's planet's gravitational field.  http://www.chakoteya.net/movies/movie1.html

Comment: What does god need with a Klingon Kird-of-prey hanging close to Earth?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

According to the film's [official novelisation](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_V:_The_Final_Frontier_(novel)), the probe had (somehow) made its way into Klingon space. No explanation is given as to quite how it managed this feat, although we do know of [other pre-warp objects from Earth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/149259/20774) that have [traveled suspiciously large distances](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/V%27ger) and non-warp-capable ships that [still managed to achieve warp velocities](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sisko%27s_lightship).

> THE ANCIENT PROBE hurtled aimlessly through the blackness of uninhabited space. Its designers were long dead, its purpose forgotten; it was now no more than a piece of flotsam, like the millions of bits of celestial debris that had collided with it, scarring its once-smooth surface. Still visible on one side of the probe, etched into the metal, were images: two naked adult humans, a male and a female, hands raised in a gesture of greeting. Beside them were various mathematical and scientific symbols. The probe had obviously been launched by humans who hoped to contact intelligent extraterrestrial life forms.
>
> **Ironic, thought First Officer Vixis, that it should encounter them here, centuries later, in the Klingon empire.**